# Reassociate arw to xmp file

Tags: adobe-camera-raw, file-recovery

My usual photo editing process (yes, I don't use Adobe Lightroom) is as follows:

1. I open my arw file in Camera Raw and modify them there (creating a xmp file)
2. I generate the jpgs
3. I retouch the jpgs

Unfortunately, after editing about 300 arw files, I accidentally deleted them (including emptying the recycle bin), remaining with the only xmps files. I managed to recover about 70% of the arw from the SD card but the filename is different so photoshop does not associate the restored arws to the proper xmps

Example:

```
a09.arw -> x37.xmp 
a10.arw -> x38.xmp 
a11.arw -> x39.xmp
```

Question: Is there an automatic way to associate the new files to their respective xmp? If I sort them alphabetically they all match, but the new filename can't be handled even with a regex replace to match the xmp file.

Comment: What do you mean "the new filename can't be handled?"